# Is there a more efficient way to search for text from ListBox in a text in C#?

Tags: c#, string, listbox

I am using Windows Forms and C#. I have a listbox that has more than 200,000 items.

I have a long string that I want to find which one of these 200,000 items appear in the string.

I wrote this code, but I wonder if there is a better way to write it:

```
string Codes = "";

foreach (string itm in lbxCodes.Items)
{
    if (Result.Contains(itm))
    { 
        Codes = Codes + "," + itm;
    }
}

return Codes;
```

Comment: Yes, there is. To start with the most obvious: make that a `List<string>` and if you really need them as one string use `string.Join` or use a `StringBuilder`. If you want to take a step back: is it the right approach in the first place? What problem are you solving and why do you keep your codes in a ListBox?

Comment: Is this perhaps an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Where does `Result` come from? How is it structured?

Comment: A ListBox is primarily a visual control. Putting 200k items in it is not just slow to process but a nightmare.

Comment: Presumably the 200K items come from somewhere and that somewhere hopefully has better facilities to search for data then shown in your code. You should look into that.

Comment: Does your current code work satisfactory? If it does there is little reason to change it. There are certainly things that could be done, list virtualization, string builder, full text search indices etc. But most things will add some complexity, so you need to consider the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two versions to improve the string handling:

## [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder)

```
StringBuilder codes = new();

foreach (string itm in lbxCodes.Items)
{
    if (Result.Contains(itm))
    { 
        codes.Append(",").Append(itm);
    }
}

return codes.ToString();
```

**Note** that this does not fix the "leading comma" bug that you also have in the original code from the question.

## `List<string>` + [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-8.0)

```
List<string> codes = new();

foreach (string itm in lbxCodes.Items)
{
    if (Result.Contains(itm))
    { 
        codes.Add(itm);
    }
}

return string.Join(",",codes);
```

**Note** : This *will not* contain a leading comma!

---

But as already mentioned in comments: It is probably a sub-par idea to keep 200k search items in a UI-Component, in the first place. So, maybe you want to reconsider this whole approach. But then it would be a different question.